# how to put text in title bar on mobile menu in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, mobile-website

cece.indiana.edu

The mobile menu works just fine; however, I can't seem to figure out how to add text in the title bar. To the right of the hamburger menu, I want text. How would I do this? I've been spending about an hour of this tiny newbie thing, but can't seem to figure it out!
[image of the title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWsuT.png)

Comment: So you want the text to be right next to the hamburger, not in the middle where it is right now?

Answer (score 1):

I just added this in the Chrome console, but add this bit after `<span class="toggle"`

```
<span class="toggle-right-title">Text</span>
```

Then the CSS should look like this

```
.toggle-right-title {
margin-left: 35px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold; }
```

You can change and customize this as need be

Answer (score 0):

The tric is to use `float: left`. Here's the CSS:

**CSS**

```
#titleBar .toggle {
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative; /*to make the float work*/
    top: 0;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left; /*the magic*/
}
#titleBar .title {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 44px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left; /*possibly what you meant*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left; /*the magic*/
}
```

Float makes the spans float next to each other, solving you problem. Hope this will help!

Comment: I changed my code a bit. Though it's not displayed on the online webpage, by creating an html element that has the id "logo" and naming it CECE, I was able to display CECE in the titlebar. However, when I do this Google Chrome recognizes the webpage as mobile, and only displays the mobile webpage. There's nothing in my CSS to say this, and it works in other browsers. I cleared my cache and am very confused.

Comment: That is peculiar. Can I see the code of this version?